# Can't get the hash() function to work in python 3.2.2

Tags: python, hash, python-idle

I have a problem with this code:

```
print('insert password below to get a hash')
pass = int(input('Input passowrd> ')

hash(pass)
input()
```

I just get a error when I try to run this, I tried the `help(hash)` in the python shell, read the docs, googled as much as possible, but I can't get it to work :-/

What is the problem?

Comment: You should tell us what error you get.

Comment: I love how nobody even mentioned that `pass` is a reserved word (and hence not a valid identifier). SO even highlights it!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two problems.

---

Firstly, a pass-**word** is not usually an integer so your call to `int` will most likely raise an exception.

You probably want this:

```
pass = input('Input password> ')
```

---

Secondly, the [`hash`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hash) function returns a [hash code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for the object for fast comparison purposes. It is not a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). Consider using something like the commonly used [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) algorithm or (preferably) something more secure like the [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) family of algorithms instead.

You can use [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) to generate hashes that are cryptographically secure. Example:

```
>>> import hashlib    
>>> hashlib.md5('admin'.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
'21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3'
>>> hashlib.sha256('admin'.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
'8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918'
```

Depending on your needs, you may also want to consider using a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to further protect the password.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works are written, but it probably isn't what you expected (the hash of an integer is just the integer itself).  Try this instead:

```
print('insert password below to get a hash')
pass_str = input('Input password: ')
h = hash(pass_str)
```

Also, if you're storing hash values for passwords and want it to be secure, be sure to use a cryptographically strong hash such as those found in the *[hashlib module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib)*:

```
>>> pass_str = 'the phrase that pays'
>>> hashlib.sha256(pass_str.encode()).hexdigest()
'a91ba2a03eb9772b114e6db5c5a114d8a9b3ba419a64cdde9606a9151c8a352e'
```

Answer (score 2):

`pass` is a statement, you can't have a variable with that name in Python.

```
>>> pass = 1
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, it would help to post the error you're getting. I bet it's a `ValueError` that complains that the password cannot be converted to an `int`, which is quite correct.

There is no point in converting to an integer in the first place; `hash` works just fine for strings:

```
print('Input password below to get a hash:')
pass = input('Input password> ')
print(hash(pass))
input()
```